# Jooma - Sharing page with no homepage shows no picture

Tags: facebook, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

i have a web site [http://www.nihangunes.com], where there is no homepage at all. it only shows a imageshow in main screen from GavickPro [https://www.gavick.com/image-show-gk4]

the issue is, as there is no home page, when i try to share my web in facebook, it doesn't have any info in the OG paramters

```
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.nihangunes.com/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
```

I am trying to find a way how to populate these parameters without adding home page. image show is working as module.

Could you suggest how can i update above og parameters for mainpage?

thanks a lot
Gurhan Cagin

Answer (score 1):

I found that GavickPro has a GK Open Graph Article Parameters plugin, and updating this plugin fixes homepage OG parameters properly.